# Eclipse error - while creating backup for 'project-desc'

Tags: java, eclipse, windows-7, eclipse-indigo, java-6

When I try to create a new Java project in eclipse indigo on Windows 7 I get the following error with a JDK 1.6:

```
An error occurred while creating project. Check log for details.

Reason:
Problem while creating backup for 'project-desc'

The system cannot find the path specified.
```

Has anybody seen this or resolved it before?

Comment: Can you check .metadata/.log in your workspace? There should be more information there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the log file told me the same thing - eclipse thought a valid directory path was invalid.

It turns out my eclipse install was corrupted - on deleting it and replacing it with a new one everything worked fine.